# Core of Windows Server name server system

Tags: windows, dns, service

I am trying to find some info about the nature of name server in Windows server, like BIND stands for Unix or Linux, for instance.

Does anyone know where can I find some tech info about the based system of a name server in Windows? Does it use a file based configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found DNS server in Windows is based on a version of BIND. 
You can edit files by hand or use its windows and dialog boxes aswell.